# chat history between a chatbot and user ( Microsoft botframework) using python language

Tags: python, azure, botframework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to save the chat conversation in the COSMOS database in the azure portal.

I have created a Cosmos account, and created a new database and container, after which I followed the steps on the official Microsoft docs, but whenever I test the bot and run it in the emulator nothing from the conversation is added to the items, like the shown in the docs. So, is there anything else I should do to save that conversation?

Note: the project is using python.

these are the steps that I did in this project to save the conversation:

1. create an Cosmos DB Account
2. add a database
3. add the Cosmos DB configuration information in the config file.
4. installing the Cosmos package using pip
5. Cosmos DB implementation like the code shown bellow.
6. run the bot locally
7. interact with the bot
   then the conversation should be displayed in the DB, but nothing is there

``this code in the bot file

```
 def init(self,config:DefaultCon):
    cosmos_config = CosmosDbPartitionedConfig(
        DBendpoint = config.COSMOS_DB_URI,
        PrimaryKey = config.COSMOS_DB_PRIMARY_KEY,
        DataBaseID = config.COSMOS_DB_DATABASE_ID,
        ContainerID = config.COSMOS_DB_CONTAINER_ID,
        compatibility_mode=False
    )
    self.storage = CosmosDbPartitionedStorage(cosmos_config)
```

``

** this code is in the config file but with the values of them

```
COSMOS_DB_URI="<your-CosmosDb-URI>"
COSMOS_DB_PRIMARY_KEY="your-primary-key"
COSMOS_DB_DATABASE_ID="<your-database-id>"
COSMOS_DB_CONTAINER_ID="bot-storage"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show more details. Currently you've only showed setting up your Cosmos DB connection. It's really not possible to know what steps you're referring to. Also, please share your setting details (be sure to obfuscate the real values regarding the URI and primary key) - it's important to know whether your settings are correct.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you David, I have edit the question. I hope this is enough to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check with the following things if possible:

1. Cosmos DB Configuration information

COSMOS_DB_URI=""

COSMOS_DB_PRIMARY_KEY="your-primary-key"

COSMOS_DB_DATABASE_ID=""

COSMOS_DB_CONTAINER_ID="bot-storage"

2. Proper installation of cosmos packages. (Suggested to use virtual environment to install the packages)

pip install botbuilder-azure

```
from botbuilder.azure import CosmosDbPartitionedStorage, CosmosDbPartitionedConfig
from config import DefaultConfig
CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

def __init__(self):
    cosmos_config = CosmosDbPartitionedConfig(
        cosmos_db_endpoint=CONFIG.COSMOS_DB_URI,
        auth_key=CONFIG.COSMOS_DB_PRIMARY_KEY,
        database_id=CONFIG.COSMOS_DB_DATABASE_ID,
        container_id=CONFIG.COSMOS_DB_CONTAINER_ID,
        compatibility_mode = False
    )
    self.storage = CosmosDbPartitionedStorage(cosmos_config)
```

Note: Creating a virtual environment in python

```
$ pip install virtualenv

$ virtualenv --version

$ virtualenv my_name - Giving suitable name for virtual environment

$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtualenv_name

$ source virtualenv_name/bin/activate - For activation

(virtualenv_name)$ deactivate - For deactivation
```

Comment: Not really needed, writing someone a troubleshooting guide. The OP needs to provide more details in their question. If you have suggestions for things to check, such as values of their settings, then those should be suggested as a comment, not an answer (there's no way to answer the question as written, as it's impossible to know the problem and document a solution, based on the lack of information provided in the question).

Comment: Also, you're posting details about things unrelated to the question, such as setting up a python environment, and installing `botbuilder-azure`.